# Scala Play and Slick. Writing Form Mapping and Database Mapping for an object

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I am using Slick 3.0 inside of Play. I have this small class for which I have written database mapping

```
case class Person(id: Int, firstname: String, lastname: String)

class People(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "PEOPLE") {
  def id = column[Int]("PERSON_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def firstname = column[String]("PERSON_FIRST_NAME")
  def lastname = column[String]("PERSON_LAST_NAME")
  def * = (id, firstname, lastname) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply _)
}
```

this compiles and works perfectly. Now I created a HTML form in which I will do data entry and i needed to bind the HTML form to the Person object. So I wrote

```
object Person {
  val form = Form(mapping(
    "id" -> number,
    "firstname" -> text,
    "lastname" -> text
  )(Person.apply)(Person.unapply))
}
```

However now I get an error message

```
[error] /Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/MyPlay1/app/tables/PersonDAO.scala:18: value tupled is not a member of object models.Person
[error]   def * = (id, firstname, lastname) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply _)
[error]                                                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Jun 28, 2015 4:37:50 PM
Mohitas-MBP:MyPlay1 abhi$
```

So it seems that addition of a companion object breaks my database mapping code. Earlier it was looking for tupled property on the case class, but now its looking int the object and it doesn't find it.

How can I have the case class and then the database mappings and the form mappings?

Comment: It's a bug of scala, you can use `(Person. apply _).tupled` instead of `Person. tupled`

Comment: this works. you should put this as an answer so that I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug of scala, you can use `(Person. apply _).tupled` instead of `Person. tupled` as an workaround